# Does copy also transfer the retain count?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Suppose I have an object, for example an NSString, with retain count 5.  When I call copy on it, I get a new copy of the object; does this new object have the retain count of its original object ?

Answer (score 6):

It depends. `copy` is a convenience method for `copyWithZone:`,
and the ["NSCopying Protocol Reference"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) states:

> Your options for implementing this protocol are as follows:
>
> - Implement `NSCopying` using `alloc` and `init...` in classes that don’t
>     inherit copyWithZone:.
> - Implement `NSCopying` by invoking the
>     superclass’s `copyWithZone:` when `NSCopying` behavior is inherited. If
>     the superclass implementation might use the `NSCopyObject` function,
>     make explicit assignments to pointer instance variables for retained
>     objects.
> - Implement `NSCopying` by retaining the original instead of
>     creating a new copy when the class and its contents are immutable.

<sub>(I have modified the following two statements after all that feedback.)</sub>

For example, `NSString` is an *immutable* object, and `copy` just retains the object
and returns a pointer to the same object. Retaining the object might increase the
retain count, but not necessarily (as in the case of string literals.)

Copying an `NSMutableString` would probably create a new object and return that.
The new object would have its own retain count independent of the original object.

But you should not care about the difference. With manual reference counting,
 `copy` returns an object that you *own* and have to *release* eventually.
With ARC, the compiler with automatically handle that.

Comment: A copy of an `NSString` instance will return a new instance of `NSString`. The underlying implementation subclass could be `NSMutableString` or any other subclass. You should not expect an immutable object copy to return the same instance.

Comment: @Benoit: That is not correct, and I checked it with a test program before posting the answer. - My point is that an *immutable* object is free to just increase the retain count for a copy, and that happens with `NSString`. I did now say that you should expect it.

Comment: @Benoit An `NSString` *may* return the same instance.  Lot's of stuff that could return a new instance returns the same instance if it makes sense: `[@"hello" stringByAppendingString:@""] == @"hello".copy`

Comment: @Benoit: I have added a link to the documentation, which states that `copy` does not necessarily return a new object.

Comment: There's no need to guess how it works. You can see for yourself how it's implemented. http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.19/CFString.c Look at `CFStringCreateCopy()`. It checks whether the string is mutable. If it isn't, and certain other corner cases aren't in play, then it just calls `CFRetain(str)` and returns the original string (exactly as MartinR says).

Comment: (Not to say you should base your usage on looking at the source code. You should read the docs and follow them as discussed above. It's just nice that you can also look at the code if you want.)

Comment: The implementation details are irrelevant.   `copy` returns an instance that is guaranteed to be a copy of the original object whose state is in isolation from said object (but whose contained object state may not be in isolation -- collections are a shallow copy).   Whether or not the copy is the same instance, a different instance of the same class or an instance of a different class is irrelevant.   To answer OP's question, the returned object has a +1 retain count (might be 1, might 42, might be -1, matters not).  You need to release it somewhere.  Assuming anything else is incorrect.

Comment: Downvote, btw, because the claim about absolute retain counts are are specious, at best, and incomplete (`NSMutableString` could do a hash lookup, for example, and return an `NSCFString` with unmodified retain count if the string were already a constant string somewhere, saving those few bytes of memory -- could, but doesn't).

Comment: @bbum: *"To answer OP's question, the returned object has a +1 retain count ... You need to release it somewhere."* - That's what I said in the last part of my answer. The statements about NSString and NSMutableString are examples, and based on the link given by Rob Napier above, they are not completely specious.

Comment: @MartinR Overly pedantic was I; fixed.  The claim that mutable string returns a new object (yes) *with retain count 1* is still misleading.  The RC may be 1, may not be;  it is an implementation detail.  While it is a pretty safe assumption that it would be 1, that it is 1 is irrelevant.  I owe you a beer.

Comment: Actually, @MartinR, your text says _"new object (with retain count 1)"_ and not "+1", now that we started reading the finer details of the answers.

Comment: @Monolo: You are right, and I think that is also what bbum criticized.  I am still thinking how to fix my answer without making the impression that I just copy bbum's answer (which is perfect, as always!).

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, I see what you mean. And btw, as a reader of these upvoted answers I don't mind them saying the same thing, as long as it is right, so I wouldn't worry too much about that. It is more important that they are right than they are different :-)

Answer (score 5):

`copy` returns an object that is a *semantic [shallow] copy*(1) of the object.   What the `copy` method returns is an implementation detail;   it may return the same object, it may return a different instance of the same class, or it might even return an instance of a different class.

Doesn't matter.

What matters is that the returned object, under manual retain/release, has a retain count of +1.  Not 1, but +1.   It might actually be 1, 42, 981, or -1.  Doesn't matter.

All that matters is that you must balance that retain with a `release` or `autorelease` somewhere if you want to relinquish the object back to the system.  Which may not actually cause it to be deallocated;  that is an implementation detail of no concern (until optimization time, anyway).

(1) *semantic [shallow] copy* means that the object returned is an effective shallow copy.  The state contained within the copied object (but not within objects contained within the object -- that is the shallow part) will not change when the original object changes state.  For a mutable object, `copy` must actually create a new instance of some object -- most likely an immutable variant class -- that can contain the original state.

For an immutable object, the `copy` method might be simply implemented as `return [self retain];`.  Or, in the case of static NSStrings (`NSCFStrings`), it might simply be `return self;` as retain/release/autorelease are no-ops on such strings.

Comment: I would hope that it would matter if the returned object has a retain count of -1.  I do like my apps to not crash randomly with _“message sent to deallocated instance”_ errors.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson -1 typically indicates a static object.

Answer (score 4):

No, a copied object will have a retain count of 1, just like a newly initialized object.

I highly recommend you read the [Memory Management Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1) if you wish to learn more.

If you're new to iOS development, the [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH1-SW1) should be read first, and is a great use of your time.

I just noticed you didn't tag this as iOS specific, if you're coding for Mac, the [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) guide might be more appropriate for you.

Comment: Unless of course, no copying actually took place since the object is immutable, e.g. `id a = @[], b = a.copy;`. But that's just an argument why you really should not focus on `retainCount`.

Comment: @BrianNickel how does immutability affect `copy`ing?

Comment: *"a copied object will have a retain count of 1"* - This is not correct, at least not in all cases.

Comment: @Eimantas, as mentioned in MartinR's answer, immutable objects often return the same instance of the object from `copy`.  The rationale is that if an object is immutable, no changes will ever occur to it, so it will always contain the same data that a copy would at this moment.  No reason to increase the memory use.

Answer (score 2):

To really get your head around this issue, don't think in terms of retain count, think in terms of pointer ownership (like ARC does).

If an object has a "retain count" of 5, that means five pieces of code somewhere are each holding a (strong) pointer to its memory address. If you `copy` that object, you get a pointer to the address of the new, copied object. The other five pieces of code are still pointing to the original object. There's only one piece of code pointing to the new object, so its "retain count" is one.

As noted in other answers, the [Memory Management Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/) definitely helps make this all clear.

Why did I put "retain count" in quotes? Because it's only useful as a general concept -- you shouldn't be using `retainCount` directly, or you'll hear from @bbum.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C plays some clever tricks when you ask it to copy objects, and as a result retain counts might not be what you think they should be.

Let's say you have an object pointer x with a retain count of n, and call the copy method which returns an object pointer y.

```
NSObject* x = ...; 
NSObject* y = [x copy];
```

Then the rule is that if you release x n times, and release y once, all objects will be gone. Usually this is achieved by leaving x unchanged, and giving y a retain count of 1.

However, if x points to an immutable object, then Objective-C may decide that no copy needs to be done. The result is that y = x. Still, the rule above still applies: Releasing x n times and y once (even though they are the same object) will free all the objects involved. That's achieved by the copy method returning x with a +1 retain count.

Answer (score 0):

Copy on mutable object like NSMutableArray will create a new copy and retain count will be 1 while copy immutable object like NSArray will point to same reference and increase the retain count by 1.